# com.apple.WebKit.Networking continually asking to sign using "privateKey"

Tags: keychain

Title sums it up, pretty frequently, once an hour or so at work I get a pop up asking me to "always allow" "deny", or "allow" WebKit to sign using my private keychain. At this point I've answered it pretty much all ways and it keeps coming up.

Some information that may be relevant:

- I'm not logged in as an administrator, but a normal privileged user
- Happens most frequently when I log in
- I have to use an invalid certificate to access a certain website for work. The pop up doesn't seem correlated with that website though
- I'm on the beta release track of MacOS

Any ideas on how to make it stop? Comments about what more information I could provide would be welcome as well.

Comment: Same issue, I'm also on the Beta.

Comment: Same issue, and I'm not on a beta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue with my company SSO certificate, it's a known issue in MacOS Sierra 10.12

Temporary workaround available:

Open Keychain Access.
Select your login keychain and then the private key "YOUR ID/Company SSO Server" (Do not search for the item but find and select ... searching will not work properly to access the ACL option)

1. Open Keychain Access.
2. Select your login keychain and then the private key "" (Do not search for the item but find and select ... searching will not work properly to access the ACL option)
3. Double-click the key to show the key's info window select the tab "Access Control"
4. Click the + button at the bottom of the window and add /Applications/Safari.app
5. Click the + button at the bottom of the window and add /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.WebKit.Networking.xpc
6. Click Save Changes and authenticate to allow those changes
7. Quit Keychain Access.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue. After some searching I simply started Safari while holding down the "Option" key. This seems to reset some stuff. This is when the issue disappeared. Even when starting Safari without the option key. Maybe it will help you as well.

(it now only asks me when the site which is using the private key is being opened, which is logical)

Comment: This sounds weird, but it actually works.

Answer (score -3):

FYI.
I found an article stating its a virus.
https://hotvirusmalwareremoval.com/steps-remove-com-apple-webkit-networking-xpc-mac/

Comment: com.apple.WebKit.Networking.xpc is not a virus. The website hotvirusmalwareremoval[.]com is a link bait website to sell malware removal software.

Comment: The original question asks about com.apple.WebKit.Networking and not com.apple.WebKit.Networking.xpc